# Determining which Dashboards have not been run in a long time

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have to create a report on Dashboards which haven't been run in a long time. I could not find `last run date` on Dashboard. How can I create this report?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think statistics are kept on dashboards, but you can generate a report on Reports and find the Last Run date for various reports. Since Dashboards are collections of reports that might be a good starting point.

**Update**

I found a Salesforce [knowledge article](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004237) that indicates a dashboard's "refresh" date is not reportable, though they offer something of a workaround.

1. Create a Custom Report Type (CRT) based on Reports and Dashboards as the child element.
2. Create a report using the new CRT
3. Sort by dashboard and check the report's Last Run Date.

With the reports grouped by Dashboard this may give you more information, though reports used in multiple Dashboards are still a problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have been doing the same but it's bit tedious because a report can be related to multiple dashboard. Now if report A is linked to Dashboard B and C. And, Dashboard B ran last Month it changed report A Last Run date. pheeww..

Comment: Is there a simple to find out the same ? thanks a lot in advance.